# Show 'Advanced Custom Field' Image

Tags: image, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having problems getting the image field from Advanced Custom Field plugin. I'm using it to set an image for custom taxonomy category named "aktuelni_ponudi_category". I have displayed the name of the category and its link, but can't fix the problem with the image.  I also want to create a shortcode, so here is my code:

```
function my_vc_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'aktuelni_ponudi_category',
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    )); ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->cat_ID); ?>">
            <?php echo $category->name; ?>
        </a>
        <?php echo '<img src="' . the_field('acf_image') . '">'; ?>
    </div>
    <?php }
    ?>
</div>
<?php }
add_shortcode( 'my_vc_php_output', 'my_vc_shortcode');
```

I'm hoping for an answer...

Comment: What have you tried so far, Viktor? What unexpected output are you getting?

Comment: I get this in 'Inspect Element' <img src(unknown)>

Comment: And what have you tried, so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom fields on a taxonomy term there is a special syntax to get that data: you should call the field function with a parameter composed of the taxonomy name and the term id, like here:

```
the_field('acf_field','aktuelni_ponudi_category_' . $category->cat_ID);
```

You can read more about it here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/